# Monomorphism restriction triggered when generic instance defined

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

type family F r

class (Functor t) => T t r where
  fromScalar :: r -> t r

data Foo t r where
  Foo :: t (F r) -> Foo t r
  Scalar :: r -> Foo t r

toF :: r -> F r
toF = undefined

convert :: (T t (F r))
  => Foo t r -> Foo t r
convert (Scalar c) = 
  let fromScalar' = fromScalar
  in Foo $ fromScalar' $ toF c
```

This code compiles with GHC 7.8.4.

When I add a generic instance for `T` (which requires `FlexibleInstances`):

```
instance (Functor t, Num r) => T t r
```

GHC complains:

```
Could not deduce (Num (F r)) arising from a use of ‘fromScalar’
    from the context (T t (F r))
      bound by the type signature for
                 convert :: (T t (F r)) => Foo t r -> Foo t r
      at Main.hs:(17,12)-(18,23)
    In the expression: fromScalar
    In an equation for ‘fromScalar'’: fromScalar' = fromScalar
    In the expression:
      let fromScalar' = fromScalar in Foo $ fromScalar' $ toF c
```

I remembered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829524/type-inference-in-patterns), but there seem to be some key differences. First and most important, GHC didn't complain pre-instance. Second, I don't have `RankNTypes`, which seemed to be at the core of the problem with that question. Finally, adding `NoMonoLocalBinds` doesn't help. Strangely, adding `NoMonomorphismRestriction` *does* change the error message from complaining about `fromScalar` to the same message about `fromScalar'`.

Of course the problem can be fixed by adding a type signature to `fromScalar` and adding `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
convert :: forall t r . (T t (F r))
  => Foo t r -> Foo t r
convert (Scalar c) = 
  let fromScalar' = fromScalar :: F r -> t (F r)
  in Foo $ fromScalar' $ toF c
```

I'm willing to concede something screwy with monomorphic types is at work here, even though removing the restrictions didn't help. My question is: why is the restriction triggered by the addition of a generic instance? More importantly, why does GHC try to match the generic instance instead of using the `T (F r)` constraint? That seems plain wrong, and smells of [this bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10195).

Comment: You're right, it may be the same bug. It's probably worth testing if it's now fixed in HEAD / the 7.10.2 branch. The problem seems to be that the added instance provides GHC with two ways to reduce the `T t (F r)` constraint arising from the use of `fromScalar'`, and for some reason, GHC chooses to apply the instance rather than the dictionary provided to `convert`.

Comment: If that's true, my luck is terrible...I managed to find the same bug again in a completely different setting!

Comment: It turns out this bug is different from [#10195](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10195). You can read more [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10338).

Comment: @Eric you should post that it was a bug as an answer so this question can move off "unasnwered" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is GHC bug [#10338](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10338). Unfortunately it doesn't look like it's going to get resolved anytime soon.