# Haskell - let binding chooses wrong instance

Tags: haskell

The following Test took me by surprise

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Test where

class Type t where
    encodeToField :: t -> String

class Rec r where
    encodeToRec :: r -> String

data X a b = X a b

instance (Type t) => Rec t where
    encodeToRec = encodeToField

instance (Type t, Rec r) => Rec (X t r) where
    encodeToRec (X t r) =
        let x = encodeToField t
            y = encodeToRec r
         in x ++ y
```

ghc fails on this with

```
Test.hs:19:17
Could not deduce (Type r) arising from a use of `encodeToRec'
from the context (Type t, Rec r)
```

For some reason ghc wants to use the `Type t => Rec t` instance at `y = encodeToRec r`, instead of just taking the `Rec r` from the context of the instance declaration.

If I avoid the let binding and instead write

```
instance (Type t, Rec r) => Rec (X t r) where
    encodeToRec (X t r) = encodeToRec t ++ encodeToRec r
```

it compiles.

Is this a bug in ghc or should that behaviour be expected because of the language extensions used?

Comment: Haven't figured this out yet, but I've found that a simpler program makes the problem show up: if you define `newtype Foo a = Foo a`, then define an instance `Rec r => Rec (Foo r)`, with `encodeToRec (Foo r) = x where x = encodeToRec r`, it gives the same error. Even though the instance doesn't refer to `Type` at all. Strange...

Comment: @AdamR.Nelson Thanks for the simplification. I didn't feel like working that out, hope that OP isn't too long :-)

Comment: This seems strange. The `++` expression should not typecheck since `t` doesn't have the constraint `Rec` ?

Comment: Yes, typeclasses cannot do this kind of specializing selection, because of the way type inference happens. The `(Type t) => Rec t` instance will always be chosen, no matter what.  You can think of instance matching going in reverse -- first we look for `Rec t` and see if the `t` matches our type (which it definitely will), and only after we have committed to that choice do we go on to check the `(Type t)` constraint.

Comment: But if you want to typecheck your original program with the `let -in` expression, just add a `Type r` constraint to it.

Comment: @Sibi: But `Type r` is not what I want.

Comment: This does not answer.. but: overlapping instances make the code too fragile, IMHO, and are rarely worth the candle. Knowing which instance is the one which is being used is tricky, and relying on it looks quite dangerous to me. (In Agda at least you can pass instances explicitly, if you really want, so they are not so evil.)

Comment: @luqui: If I get you right, I should avoid creating instances like `Type t`, just because the "type pattern" `t` matches any type (ignoring any constraints on the instance)?

Comment: @JoSo: that's right, don't do `instance (Bar t) => Foo t`, as it basically limits your class to that one instance (so you could as well define the class methods as top-level functions).

Answer (score 1):

This smells a lot like a [known bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10338): your code compiles when I remove the generic instance, but GHC doesn't find a supplied constraint in its presence. I have a corresponding SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763655/monomorphism-restriction-triggered-when-generic-instance-defined).
If this is the same bug, it might not be fixed for a while (if ever).

Comment: Are you sure both the bug are same ? The example shown in the linked ticket involves type family. Probably file another ghc issue to get confirmation ? Will you do that or shall I file an issue ? (There is no harm in asking ghc-devs if it is a bug even if it is a duplicated of the linked bug.)